# Contact Form Not Response on mail sending?

Tags: plugins, contact-form-7

i can use contact form 7 for one site. there is a issue on mail sending. when i click send button mail received but response message not shown. ajax loader image will be loading continuously.

Comment: Please check the developer console. Do you see any error there?

Comment: In Google Chrome firstly check the "Networks" tab in your developer tools and set filter to XHR. Than try to send a message and take a look at the request.

Comment: Did you configured settings like your email.?